# Focus on the current day when switching to month view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

Is there a way to focus on the current day when switching to month view?

I would like to view the calendar like this.

[image]

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-standard-view-demo

Comment: Are you using the react implementation of this library `@fullcalendar/react` ?

Comment: yes, and I still haven't figured out how to do this.